# Solving environment: failed when install RAPIDS using conda

Tags: python, conda, rapids

In order to install `RAPIDS`, I get the command from the site below and run it, but the following error occurs.

https://docs.rapids.ai/install

```
conda create --solver=libmamba -n rapids-23.08 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia rapids=23.08 python=3.10 cuda-version=12.0
```

---

```
Channels:
 - rapidsai
 - conda-forge
 - nvidia
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443  "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443  "GET /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443  "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443  "GET /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
/ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443  "GET /rapidsai/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
- DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443  "GET /pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443  "GET /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443  "GET /rapidsai/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - rapids=23.08*

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai 
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge 
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia 
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org 

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

---

OS : Windows Server 2022 Datacenter

Python : 3.10.12

conda : 23.7.3

cuda : 12.0

Comment: Are you running this within a [WSL2](https://docs.rapids.ai/install#wsl2) environment?

Comment: Reason I ask is that it looks like the `rapidsai` conda repository only has linux versions of the `rapids` library

Comment: @Jeff, I'm trying it in anaconda on windows server

Comment: I don't have experience with Windows Server, but I think your issue is you need to be running `conda` in a Linux environment, which on Windows means WSL. If you have admin privileges you can try [installing WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-distros-are-now-supported-on-windows-server/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAPIDS libraries currently support Linux and WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux 2) operating systems. The conda output in the question shows `Platform: win-64` which is not supported.

The RAPIDS installation guide gives more detailed information about supported platforms, supported GPUs, and how to set up WSL2 for Windows users: https://docs.rapids.ai/install

The recommendation for Windows users is to use Windows 11 with a WSL2 instance of Ubuntu 22.04. You mentioned you have Windows Server 2022, which appears to support WSL2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server). I expect that Windows Server 2022 should work fine.